# Unabe to parse date of different culture

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to parse date

```
var newDateTime = new Date(Date.parse($("#SelctedCalendarDay").val()));
```

`$("#SelctedCalendarDay").val()` value is 14-okt-2014 in string.

When the date is 14-Oct-2014 it parses it correctly.

So how can I parse this date 14-okt-2014?

Comment: Can you look at the correspondance in langage option of your calendar plugins ?

Comment: yes i using nl language

Comment: Yeah but all the different langages must be set in your plugins, look how it is written and get the correspondance of okt in english.

Comment: Don't use the Date constructor to parse strings, it is completely unreliable. Write your own parser, it's perhaps 4 lines of code.

Comment: can u plz help me @RobG

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what language you are using (Dutch?) so I'll use English, it's easy to substitute whatever language you like. You can parse a date string like 14-Oct-2014 using:

```
function parseDMMMY(s) {

  // Split on . - or / characters
  var b = s.split(/[-.\/]/);

  // Months in English, change to whatever language suits
  var months = {jan:0, feb:1, mar:2, apr:3, may:4, jun:5,
                jul:6, aug:7, sep:8, oct:9, nov:10, dec:11};

  // Create a date object
  return new Date(b[2], months[b[1].toLowerCase()], b[0]);
}

console.log(parseDMMMY('14-Oct-2014')); // Tue Oct 14 2014 00:00:00
```

Note that the above will create a local date object. It doesn't do any validation of values so if you give it a string like 31-Jun-2014 you'll get a Date object for 01-Jul-2014. It's easy to add validation (it takes one more line of code), but that may not be required if you know only valid strings will be passed to the function.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of [Date.parse @ Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

> The date time string may be in ISO 8601 format. For example,
> "2011-10-10" (just date) or "2011-10-10T14:48:00" (date and time) can
> be passed and parsed. The UTC time zone is used to interpret arguments
> in ISO 8601 format that do not contain time zone information (note
> that ECMAScript ed 6 draft specifies that date time strings without a
> time zone are to be treated as local, not UTC).

It seems to me the native Date.parse does not convert date strings matching a specific locale. There also seem to be some slight differences between specific browsers.

Maybe you want to use a library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/) for that?

Or you may want to wire up some [PHP strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to your JS.

Comment: That "documentation" is a public wiki for Mozilla browsers, it does not necessarily apply to any other browser, there is nothing in the [*ECMAScript Language Specification*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.2) to support the statements in that quote, note: *If the String does not conform to [the format specified in §15.9.1.15] the function may fall back to any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats*". I.e. if the string doesn't conform to the version of ISO 8601 in ECMA-262 then parsing is completely implementation dependent.

Comment: Yup, fixed the quoted documentation. The `Date.parse` works in all browsers, but its behavior seems rather undocumented.